# Why was there a need for all of the Pym particles?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Ant-man has the idea to pull off a  time heist in order to get back the six Infinity stones and reverse the Snap. As stated in the movie, there are no second chances because they only have enough Pym particles for one time trip.

Why couldn't they send a couple of people back to find the Time Stone (which *was* the first -and easiest- one to be found), and once they have the Time Stone they can travel through time without needing the Pym particles?

Comment: It hasn’t been shown that the Time Stone allows people to travel through time; at least not in the same sense of what they did using the quantum realm.

Comment: Why is it considered that using Time stone is like a piece of cake? Only the best of the best wizards could make use of it. As mentioned by The Ancient One to Hulk that Dr. Strange is the best of them all. I see no point of just getting time stone and then spending decades understanding it's nature and how to use it to reverse everything.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Probably because Thanos made it look so easy? He used it to reverse Vision's death within about 5 minutes of obtaining it. He'd obviously spent a long time researching the stones, but not every viewer really appreciates that fact.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist At the same time, one can argue that why didn't Dr. Strange use the Time stone on Titan to simply turn Thanos into an infant? But the fact is even Dr. Strange didn't possess that much knowledge at that time about Time stone. So yes Thanos did make it look very easy but maybe Avengers already knew that this trick was way beyond their league.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> once they have the time stone they can travel through time without needing the Pym particles?

### There is no indication that the Time Stone allows *travel* through time.

Certainly the Time Stone appears to allow seeing the future and manipulation of time on a *local* scale...such as affecting an apple (*Dr. Strange*) and resurrecting the Vision (*Infinity War*) but no time *travel* has been seen.

Regardless, ALL the Infinity Stones were required by the Avengers not just the Time Stone and this required travel in **Time and Space.**

Having the Time Stone *might* have allowed the first (unproven) but not the second.

The Quantum Realm allows travel through **Space-Time** and access to that realm requires Pym particles.

Comment: Even if Time stone allows time travel, do they have an expert who can properly make use of it?

Comment: Time travel (as the trope goes) always inherently entails space travel. Otherwise, resurrecting Vision would not account for the Earth's rotation (around itself and around the sun) and thus Vision would not appear to be in the same location (to people on the surface) than he was when he initially died.

Answer (score 1):

> once they have the time stone they can travel through time without needing the Pym particles?

The answer to this is pretty simple. 
The time stone requires mastery to use it. Dr. Strange had to read books and learn a lot of things to master a few time manipulation tricks.

In as much as this might sound like a good idea, I don't think it was practical for The Avengers to go this route. There wasn't even a single wizard they could consult on this so this would be a very difficult route to work with.